# How to bring up the "Windows cannot open this file" dialog?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, file-association, process.start

My users can attach documents to various entities in the application.  Of course, if user A attaches a .TIFF file, user B may not have a viewer for that type of file.

So I'd like to be able to bring up this dialog:

[alt text http://www.angryhacker.com/toys/cannotopen.png](http://www.angryhacker.com/toys/cannotopen.png)

My application is C# with VS2005.
Currently I do Process.Start and pass in the file name.  If no association is found, it throws an exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "rundll32.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL " + yourFileFullnameHere;

p.Start();
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it brings up the dialog box every time.  I guess I should just execute this code if I get a Win32Exception stating that there is no association.

Comment: Note that `OpenAs_RunDLL` is undocumented and [does not always work.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566667/rundll32-shell32-dll)

Answer (score 15):

```
Process pr = new Process();
pr.StartInfo.FileName = fileTempPath;
pr.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true; // important
pr.Start();
```

Comment: This one's better, platform independent.